# how can create foreign key for OneToOne like OneToMany?

Tags: hibernate

Following is a json,I want to parse it and save it into mysql_db using hibernate

```
{
"company":{"name":"test","location":"test"},
"spouse":{"name":"test","year":"test"},
"sons":[
{"name":"test","year":"test"},
{"name":"test","year":"test"}]
}
```

The following is my Parent Entity

```
public class Parent {
private Company company;
private Spouse spouse;
private List<Son> sons;

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Company.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

@OneToOne(targetEntity = Son.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public Spouse getSpouse() {
    return spouse;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy="record",targetEntity = Son.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
public List<Son> getSons() {
    return sons;
}
}
```

I want all tables except Person have foreign key parent_id, unfortunately when I use OneToOne annotation,foreign key of Company and Spouse were created on the Person table.And code above does not work because I have repeated keys for Parent. What should I do to create foreign key on Company and Spouse while not changing Parent's Field?

I searched function of mappedBy field of OneToOne,but it did not work. Is it unfriendly for users that we can not switch table to create foreign key?

Any solution or explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Post the mapping that you tried so we can start from somewhere, maybe with only the relevant fields

Comment: I have added my entity,do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @JoinColumn is the annotation that tells hibernate to create the fk, you should move all those relationship to your child entities